# double click doesn't work on win8 desktop from first time

Tags: windows-8, mouse, double-click

i have win8 and double clicking works fine after entering my computer. However, on the desktop when i double click any icon it doesn't open until the third click. i tried removing the domain user from profiles but the problem returned after running the programs i have. i thought it could be related to avcast or babylon so i uninstalled babylon and prevented avast from starting but the problem persists. i am suspecting it could be because of bwmeter which installs a network driver but what has the mouse driver to do with it? any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It could be the default `Double Click Speed`.

Go to `Control Panel` - `Mouse` - `Buttons` tab and play around with the `Double Click Speed`.

This could also be a hardware issue so the above may not work. You could also try re-installing the drivers for the mouse you are using.

Comment: i tried moving the speed to the far right and the far left and the same problem and it isn't a hardware problem as after entering my computer everything clicks great

Comment: It's probably a driver problem then. What mouse are you using?

Comment: logitech mouse .

Comment: and on the other domain users on this computer there is no problem

Comment: It might be a program on just your account causing this. Did the problem begin after installing `BWMeter`?

Comment: i don't know after what program it started occuring but i just reenabled it to run at startup and i have bwmeter on another computer and works just fine

Comment: Don't run it at start-up and see what happens. You have to turn things off to rule them out. You could try disabling start-up items one by one to help find the possible cause.

Comment: well i uninstalled bwmeter and babylon which were the 2 extra things present compared to other domain users on this computer and after that i was totally unable to click icons on desktop so i right clicked and there was it catalyst something, so i uninstalled amd catalyst and it started clicking sometimes from the second click and sometimes from the third so the problem didn't go away as i supposed it would. anyway what is running in tray now is ashampoo hdd control, babylon, oultook 2013, bwmter, skype, ursa spell checker and punto switch. any more ideas what to disable?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with [Yandex's Punto Switch](http://punto.yandex.ru/) which automatically switches languages when it detects which language you are typing with.

Up to now they haven't fixed the problem.